Remove dbl quotes from dict value during dataframe .collect
iterating rows of a dataframe (code below) I need to strip the outer/enclosing double quotes from row.geometry value.
Instead of:
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": "{\"type\": \"LineString\", \"coordinates\": [[-1.1234, 2.1234], [-1.1234, 2.1234], [-1.1234, 2.1234]]}", "properties": {"district_name": "CITY"}}]}

I want to see:
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {\"type\": \"LineString\", \"coordinates\": [[-1.1234, 2.1234], [-1.1234, 2.1234], [-1.1234, 2.1234]]}, "properties": {"district_name": "CITY"}}]}

How can I do this?
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
import json

@transform(
    line_asset=Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.xxxx"),
    line_output=Output("ri.foundry.main.dataset.yyyy"),
)
def compute_function(line_asset, line_output):
    line_asset = line_asset.dataframe()
    line_asset = line_asset.limit(1)
    line_asset = line_asset.select("geometry","district_name")
    line_asset = line_asset.withColumn("district_name", F.concat_ws(",", "district_name"))
    line_asset = line_asset.repartition(2)
    geojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}

    for row in line_asset.collect():
        target_file_name = f"line_asset.json"
        feature = {"type":"Feature","geometry": row.geometry, "properties": {"district_name": row.district_name}}{"district_name": row.district_name]}}
        geojson['features'].append(feature)

    with line_output.filesystem().open(target_file_name, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(geojson, fp)


Use json.loads() to parse the JSON into a dictionary.

json.loads(row.geometry)
